# How can I get the file owner on Windows with Go?

Tags: windows, file, go

I'm trying to get file owner on Windows with Go and it's such a pain to find any help on it after hours on go `src` I found this:

```
// TODO(brainman): fix all needed for os
func Fchdir(fd Handle) (err error)             { return EWINDOWS }
func Link(oldpath, newpath string) (err error) { return EWINDOWS }
func Symlink(path, link string) (err error)    { return EWINDOWS }

func Fchmod(fd Handle, mode uint32) (err error)        { return EWINDOWS }
func Chown(path string, uid int, gid int) (err error)  { return EWINDOWS }
func Lchown(path string, uid int, gid int) (err error) { return EWINDOWS }
func Fchown(fd Handle, uid int, gid int) (err error)   { return EWINDOWS }

func Getuid() (uid int)                  { return -1 }
func Geteuid() (euid int)                { return -1 }
func Getgid() (gid int)                  { return -1 }
func Getegid() (egid int)                { return -1 }
func Getgroups() (gids []int, err error) { return nil, EWINDOWS }
```

Does it mean its not yet possible ?

I probably miss something any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May be duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840415/go-golang-file-uid-on-windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go (golang), file uid on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840415/go-golang-file-uid-on-windows)

Comment: as you obviously solved your problem it would be helpful to post the solution - so others do not have to search for hours - as you did. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File and security systems are operating system specific. Go is modeled on Linux, Darwin, and other Unix-like operating systems. The Go Windows port emulates most things, but, as you have discovered, not everything (some are just stubs). If the  features you need are not in the Go standard library, look for independently written, open-source Go packages. The last resort is to write your own interface to the Microsoft Windows API.

Comment: I figured it few after posting my questions.
Btw i found this library on github which could be helpfull.
https://github.com/hectane/go-acl